# What's the difference between shorting "borrowed" shares and "fake" shares

Tags: options, option-pricing

Like it or not, millions of people are now looking to r/wallstreetbets for not only memes but to view shared investment research.

I've learned a lot about stock options in the past year, but I'd like to quote a "due dilligence" post on wallstreetbets [claiming GME was shorted 33,000,000+ non-existent shares and it's illegal or should be.](https://www.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/comments/lsvl8k/really_long_dd_and_analysis_what_happened/) It talks about a certain number of borrowed and non-existent "fake" shares.

[image]

In the post he cites [this article on counterfitting stocks](http://counterfeitingstock.com/CounterfeitingStock.html#:%7E:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20this,the%20company%2C%20is%20considered%20counterfeit)

From my understanding of options, this doesn't make sense.

To short a stock, you

A: sell to open a call option contract, making the agreement that if the stock closes on X date above Y value, you'll sell the buyer 100 shares at Y value. You're betting these terms wont be met and you'll take the buyer's money, paying them nothing in return.

B: buy a put option contract, making the aggreement that if the stock closes on X date below Y value, the seller will buy 100 shares from you at Y value.

C: Is there any other way?

Both of these scenarios create a short position, often done in combination with other options as part of spreads.

In both of these cases, let's say there are 1,000,000 shares and you're taking a short position equal to 2,000,000 shares via selling to open calls. It seems to me if you lose that bet, you can meet your obligations by buying 1,000,000 shares and selling them to fill half of your obligations, then re-buying them and selling them at the agreed upon price. Financial suicide? Yes. Illegal? No.

Isn't this what people mean when they talk about hedge funds buying shares to cover their short positions? And the huge demand drives up the price creating a "short squeeze" (rise in price)? Does such a scenario damage the market? It is something bad that shouldn't exist?

Comment: When you short a stock, you have usually two days to settle the trade (i.e. deliver the stock). If you close out your position on the same day when you shorted or the day after, you will never need to borrow the stock you shorted.

Comment: On the buyside, you have to get locate before you short, irrespective of your expected holding period.

Comment: Rather than borrowed vs fake it would be more accurate and standard to talk about covered vs naked short sales. You can google these terms.  In the US there are rules against naked short sales, but they are not always enforced.

Comment: here is a nice writeup from the horse's mouth (the SEC) about reg SHO. https://www.sec.gov/investor/pubs/regsho.htm Not all naked short sales are against the rules in the U.S.  But indeed rule 203 - Locate Requirement  (market makers are mostly exempt) a broker-dealer to have reasonable grounds to believe that the security can be borrowed so that it can be delivered on the date delivery is due before effecting a short sale order. This “locate” must be made and documented prior to effecting the short sale.

Comment: Also, here is a web page www.firstamericanstock.com/index.php/articles/why-is-naked-short-selling-both-illegal-and-common-practice/ that says: "The Depository Trust & Clearing Corporation or DTCC (the final depository where all U.S. trades are settled and cleared) cannot settle fraudulent trades. According to the DTCC website, “We don’t have any power or legal authority to regulate or stop short-selling, naked or otherwise.” While DTCC may not have the authority to regulate any short selling, it could create computer programs that would track share holdings to determine if (cont)

Comment: continuing to quote www.firstamericanstock.com/index.php/articles/why-is-naked-short-selling-both-illegal-and-common-practice/ "if they are real shares or simply entitled. Some believe that the DTCC chooses not to monitor these transactions more closely, because they make money on the interest and the loaning of these shares... Perhaps it is time for DTCC to “enter the age of transparency” and build a much-needed tracking system into their clearing and settlement software."

Answer (score 2):

First, remember that only anyone who sells a naked call or put will get market to market and have to put up cash as it moves.   The market makers who do the bulk of the trading will never sell an outright, naked option.   They will always hedge with the actual stock.  So you might be buying a put, but the person selling it to you is going to sell a share of the underlying stock to hedge.

Secondly, The article that you linked to throws a lot of terms at you but is misleading in many ways.  The way the sytem works today every sold share will be located from a lender.   That means that if you go to your E-Trade , or TD, or whatever, and sell stock X - they have sourced those shares from a long holder.  That is a strong legal requirement and people get it trouble if they break it.

The DTCC and NSCC are just computer systems for facilitating the delivery of the shares, nothing else.  If you don't have a locate for the shares the system won't magically get it for you.

If a broker doesn't have a locate then the stock won't come in from the DTCC/CNS.  Then you get an extra day or so to find it.  If you can't find it you (the dealer) has to buy it!   And then the dealer can get "put in the box" where they will be prohibited from lending that name for a while.   Dealers are very careful because it will cost them customer business if they can't short a name when their competitors can!

Answer (score 1):

*C: Is there any other way?* - yes, borrow the shares and go short.

*Does such a scenario [short squeeze] damage the market? It is something bad that shouldn't exist?* - how do you define that?

re B - your options could be cash-settled. Doesn't necessarily affect the seller's hedging strategy, just pointing it out.